# how to get nginx proxy_pass response header

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

This is my environment： client --> nginx --> server

I set the following settings in nginx,like this：

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xx;
    }
}
```

when nginx proxy_pass to the server ,and the server returns a response, status code is 302， it also adds a custom header

and the nginx how to gets the header returned by the server ，Need to do processing based on the response returned

Comment: Did you get the answer of this question? I am also looking for
 it.